Temporary object can bind to non-const reference?
#include <iostream>
class A{
    public:
     int a=5;
    int& g(){
        return a;
    }
    A f(){
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A obj;
    std::cout<<obj.f().g();
return 0;}

      

I think that obj.f() is a temporary object.
Why can its data member has reference?
I thought that the compiler should have told me something like "can't bind a non-const lvalue reference to a rvalue...".
I took out the g function from class A and put it outside:
int& g(A& obj){ 
return obj.a; }

Then the compiler complains. I think my question is that why this can't work but the former can.
Thanks for answering me.

it is valid to use this temporary on this line (temporary lifetime extends to the end of the statement), and you code is 100% correct, it is just that using this int& on the next line would be undefined behavior.

Yes for class rvalue this is allowed. There are slightly different rules for class rvalue.

Why is it possible to assign to an rvalue of class type? and What can be done to prevent misleading assigment to returned value?

I don't think that duplicate answers this question

I believe it's called Temporary materialization

@Caleth See the updated dupe. It should answer it. and show a workaround. This answer in particular.

@user12002570 It's not that either. An id-expression naming a data member is always an lvalue

@Caleth Are you saying obj.f() is an lvaue? It is an rvalue afaik .

No, I'm saying that a in A::g() is, irrespective of what this points to

@Caleth Maybe I am misinterpreting the question in which case I'll reopen if needed. But obj.f() shouldn't have anything to do with a right? I mean g is called on the returned temporary not a.

@user12002570 OP's confusion is that they think it does. It doesn't

I took out the g function from class A and put it outside:
int& g(A& obj){
return obj.a;
}.         Then the compiler complains. I think my question is that why can't this work but the one in my article can.

as for your update, A is a temporary so it is A&& and you cannot bind A&& to A&, you can however bind it to const A&, so if you change your function to take and return const& instead it would compile, this doesn't change the object lifetime.

and i need to drop this here Thoughts on “The C++ Rvalue Lifetime Disaster”

@123 unfortunately only CV qualifiers are propagated to children, and you are doing the equivalent of this, https://godbolt.org/z/94hE1PcE7 , i would refer to @HolyBlackCat answer as to why this works, basically rvalues are lvalues in the function body when they are given a name, it doesn't matter if they were originally rvalues, if they have a name they are lvalues.

@Ahmed AEK Thank you. But I am still a little confused: like this one: int& foo(int a){return a;} this is usually forbidden even though "a" has a name.(Actually I'm not sure if it will extend to the end of the statement, like "int b=foo(5); ")    In my article, I think that obj.f() is also something that will not exist after the stament ends; I don't understand why taking the reference of this is Ok, but in my foo example is not accepted.

@123 int& foo(int a){return a;} this will compile and is not UB, accessing its returned reference is UB, C++ doesn't prevent you from making bugs, as in your initial example taking a reference is okay, using it on the next line is UB, C++ does have some amount of type safety as you saw, but due to legacy constraints and the requirements of fast compile times not all UB is caught, and you can shoot yourself in the foot, you can use a language like rust to avoid those potential bugs, but rust has horrible compile times so it cannot be used for large scale apps, only small services.

@Ahmed AEX sorry for bothering you again. You mentioned that temporary lifetime extends to the end of the statement. Then with int& foo(int a){return a;} if I later write cout<<foo(5); in main, why can't it work correctly? The copied returned value and the variable on the stackframe of foo should have been alive in that statement.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


I think that obj.f() is a temporary object.

Yes, it is a temporary object. It lives until the end of the full expression where it is created.

Why can its data member has reference?

Because an expression naming a data member is always an lvalue. It doesn't matter if you ref-qualify A::g, the expression a keeps it's value category.
Having said that, you could hint to users that g returns a member, by overloading it thus:
class A{
    public:
     int a=5;
    int& g() &{
        return a;
    }
    int&& g() &&{
        return std::move(a); // N.b. move is required because a is an lvalue here too
    }
    A f(){
        return *this;
    }
};

Alternately, you can forbid obj.f().g() by only lvalue-ref qualifying g, or by explicitly = deleteing the rvalue-ref overload
#include <iostream>

class A{
    public:
     int a=5;
    int& g() &{
        return a;
    }
    A f(){
        return *this;
    }
};

class B{
    public:
     int a=5;
    int& g() &{
        return a;
    }
    int&& g() && = delete;
    B f(){
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A obj1;
    B obj2;
    std::cout<<obj1.f().g(); // error: passing 'A' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers
    std::cout<<obj2.f().g(); // error: use of deleted function 'int&& B::g() &&'
    return 0;
}

See it on coliru

For the last snippet I would add int&& g() && = delete; to make the intent clear. int&& g() && = delete("To prevent misuse on reference to temporary data member"); for C++26.

Thak you. Let me clarify: Once a object call its member function , whether it is temporary or not, the function will take it as a lvalue. Right?

Your original A::g() can be called on either an lvalue A or an rvalue. Within any member function, the expression a (or this->a) is an lvalue

Objects exist in memory at runtime. They can be temporary (if constructed in a certain manner) or not.
Expressions are parts of the source code referring to objects, they only exist at compile-time. They can be lvalues or rvalues.
Multiple expressions can refer to the same object, and have different values categories (lvalue vs rvalue).
Yes, an expression that creates a temporary is (always?) an rvalue, but that doesn't mean you can't get an lvalue expression referring to the same object.
obj.f() indeed creates a temporary A object, and this expression is an rvalue. But the a expression in return a; is an lvalue regardless.
In general, all "names" are lvalues, for safety reasons. If a was a class for which copying and moving behave differently, and you did auto x = a, y = a;, this would break if a was an rvalue. (There are exceptions to this rule, such as local variables being implicitly moved in return statements.)

This has to do with the difference between objects and expressions.
Reference binding is governed by certain rules that are enforced by the type system. These rules relate the type of a reference, such as int&, with the kinds of expressions that the reference can bind to. For example, a reference of type int& can bind only to

an lvalue of type int, or
an expression of class type with a conversion function to an lvalue of type int.

Violating these rules results in a compile error.
There are also other reference binding rules that are not enforced by the type system that have to do with what types of objects a reference can bind to. A reference of type int& can bind only to

an object of type (possibly cv-qualified) int, or
an object of type (possibly cv-qualified) unsigned int.

Violating these rules results in undefined behaviour at runtime.
Now, what about the rule that a non-const lvalue reference is not allowed to bind to a temporary object? It turns out that that's not really the rule. When it comes to what kinds of objects a reference is allowed to bind to—restrictions of the second kind—there are no such restrictions related to the storage duration of the object. Any kind of reference is permitted to bind to an object with automatic, static, dynamic, thread-local, or temporary storage duration. (Of course, you have to be careful about the possibility of the reference becoming a dangling reference at some point.)
But restrictions of the first kind often get in the way. An int& can bind to an lvalue of int, but not an xvalue or prvalue. For example, int& r = 1; will not compile because 1 is a prvalue, not an lvalue. Many expressions that refer to temporary objects are xvalues (or they're prvalues that are materialized into xvalues), but it's also possible to get a different "view" of the same object, i.e., the fact that there's an xvalue expression referring to an object, such as a temporary object, doesn't prevent there from also being an lvalue expression referring to the same object. And that's what's happening here: obj.f() is a prvalue, and if you were to write obj.f().a, it would be an xvalue. But you can also call g, and when g views that same subobject, it does so through the expression this->a, which is an lvalue (because this is a pointer, and dereferencing a pointer always gives you an lvalue). So an int& is allowed to bind to that expression.

Do you mean that obj.f() is a prvalue but in g() it is a lvalue?or it is stil a rvalue but this->a is a lvalue ? That confuses me...

@123 obj.f() is a prvalue. Inside g, the same object can be referred to by *this, but it's an lvalue. The expression used to refer to an object, not the object itself, is what can be an lvalue or rvalue.

About «I think that obj.f() is a temporary object. Why can its data member has reference?» – you are confusing the concepts a little.
It is indeed impossible to create a lvalue reference to a data member of a temporary object – there would be an error when trying to compile code:
int& b = obj.f().a;

But there is no requirement in the standard to prohibit compiling class methods for temporary objects if these methods use lvalue references or pointers to data members of such objects. Those for example you can write:
std::cout << (std::vector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } [3] = -77) << std::endl;

and it  compiles.
The only exception is an array rvalue. For such arrays the subscript expression a[n] should be xvalue. Those the following code should not compile:
using T5elemArray = int[5];
std::cout << (T5elemArray{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } [3] = -77) << std::endl;

But this requirement is not fulfilled by all compilers – g++ and clang++ gives an error, but msvc compiles the above code.
In fact in your example something else is more interesting.
By adding a destructor to your code:
~A()
{
    std::cout << "destructor A\n";
}

and rewriting the function main() as follows:
int main()
{
    A obj;
    int&& rref = obj.f().a;
    std::cout << "finish main\n";
    return 0;
}

you can see that the lifetime of the temporary object obj.f() is extended until the end of the function main() execution. This is because obj.a is a xvalue.

I think that the vector example works because the overlaoded<<take const reference as parameter. Doesn't it?

No, it’s because vector::operator[] returns lvalue reference.  If you take class A from your example, you can write: std::cout << (A().g() = 7) << std::endl; and it compiles. That is such a code is correct, although meaningless


I think that obj.f() is a temporary object Why can its data member has reference?

Yes, it is a temporary object and the expression obj.f() is of type A and has a value category of rvalue. And the standard allows calling a member function on class rvalues.
Thus, you're essentially calling the member function g on the result of obj.f().

Temporary object can bind to non-const reference?

You're not actually binding the temporary object to the non-const reference of type int&.
